# Choosing Functions for the Squeeze Theorem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+...+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}$$

$$$$
I came across the the question on this site itself but had a few doubts on the given solution. As I do not yet have 50 reputation points, I cannot comment over there. Could somebody please help me?
$$$$
From what I understand of the Squeeze Theorem, the three functions are related as 
$$g(x)\le f(x)\le h(x)$$
$$$$
Now in the selection of terms, the following inequality has been used:
$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}} \leq \frac{1}{n}  $$when $0 \leq k \leq 2n$
$$$$
This inequality lead to the one used as the three functions for the application of the Squeeze theorem:

$$\frac{2n+1}{n+1} \leq S(n) \leq \frac{2n+1}{n}$$
where $S(n)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+...+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}$
$$$$
I don't understand how $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}} $$
$$$$
Isn't $$n^2+k\le n^2+2n<(n+1)^2 \Rightarrow n^2+k<(n+1)^2$$
$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{n^2+k}< (n+1)$$$$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}$$

$$$$
Thus shouldn't the resulting set of inequalities be $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}} \leq \frac{1}{n}  $$

$$\Longrightarrow \frac{2n+1}{n+1} < S(n) \leq \frac{2n+1}{n}$$

$$$$

In this case there is a $<$ sign instead of the $\le$ sign. How then can the Squeeze Theorem be applied?
Many thanks in advance.
$$$$
EDIT: Also, since Limits preserve Inequalities, how can $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2n+1}{n+1} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n+1}{n}$$ when $$\frac{2n+1}{n+1} <  \frac{2n+1}{n}$$

Comment: Well $0<1/n$ for all $n.$ Yet $\lim 1/n = 0.$

Comment: Also note $a<b \implies a\le b.$

Comment: The last term is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}$, which is greater than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n+1}}=\frac{1}{n+1}$, and all the terms before that are even bigger.

Comment: @zhw. True, but then I had read that Limits always preserve Inequalities in several contexts, whereas this doesn't seem to be the case. Is there a specific framework within which the Inequalities are preserved?

Comment: They do not preserve **strict** inequality.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Alright Sir, thanks very much!

Comment: @zhw. Sorry Sir, I know this is a silly question, but could you please explain why $$a<b \implies a\le b.$$ From my interpretation of $\le$, it means that one of the two quantities compared might be lesser $or$ equal to the other, $$$$But wouldn't $<$ imply that one of the quantities is $always$ lesser than the other?

Comment: For the lower inequality you can use $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2n}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + k}}$ which holds for all $k \leq 2n$. This leads to $\frac{2n+1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2n}} < S < \frac{2n+1}{n}$ which is ready to be squeezed.

Comment: But Sir, for using the Squeeze theorem, don't both the signs have to be greater than or equal to ie $\le$?

Comment: @Winther I Had learnt that the functions must be of the form $$g(x)\le f(x)\le h(x)$$ whereas you have written $$g(x)< f(x)< h(x)$$. Could you please tell me what all combinations are allowed? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is allowed. All you need to know is that $f$ lies between $g$ and $h$. If $f$ happens to equal $g$ or $h$ then that does not change anything.

Comment: Alright Sir, thanks very much!

Answer (score 5):

Limits don't necessarily preserve *strict* inequalities.  For example, $1-\frac{1}{n}<1+\frac{1}{n}$, yet they have the same limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $a<b\implies a\le b$. This is because $a\le b$ means $a<b$ or $a=b$ as you already noted in the comment.

If you are still confused, recall that "$p\implies q$" means $q$ is true whenever $p$ is true. And when $a<b$ is true, $a<b$ or $a=b$ is true. Hence, $a<b\implies a\le b$.

For example, is "$0\le 1$" true?

Comment: But doesn't $a<b$ (ie a is less than b) rule out $a\le b$ (ie a is less than or equal to b)?$$$$ I thought so since $a<b$ necessarily means that $a$ is $smaller$ than $b$, and thus $cannot$ be $equal$ to b (as it is smaller than b).

Comment: Of course $a<b$ rules out $a=b$ but not $a\le b$.